# How to access stack base pointer (rbp) using inline assembly?

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly, icc

My requirement is to access a function call parameters by offsetting rbp using inline assembly. But I couldn't find a suitable operand constraint to specify the base pointer in x86. I am using Intel compiler but it's documentation states that it supports GCC style inline assembly. So GCC based example would be sufficient.

Comment: Of all x86 calling conventions I'm aware of, whether 32bit or 64bit, _none mandates_ the use of `EBP`/`RBP` as framepointer. The ability to access arguments relative to the framepointer (register) is therefore ... dependent on how exactly your code was compiled. In 64bit x86 on UN*X, you cannot normally access arguments through `%rbp` at all because they're not passed on the stack / they don't exist in memory (but only in the arg registers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 uint64_t n;

 __asm__ __volatile__(
   "movq %%rbp, %0\n\t"
   : "=r"(n)
 );

 printf("rbp = 0x%" PRIx64 "\n", n);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great thanks. This seems to work. Can you also explain how to do an base pointer offset addressing with this if possible? (e.g: "movq 10(%%rbp), %0\n\t" - This doesn't work for me)

Answer (score 5):

I know you asked for inlined assembly, but note that on gcc you could also use `__builtin_frame_address`, which both frees you from the need for inlined assembly (yikes), and could provide frame levels further than the immediate one.

See here - 
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html

Comment: Seems pretty useful. Not sure about the Intel compiler support though for these.

Comment: @chamibuddhika, well, I couldn't find any guarantees but I just test it with icc 11 and it gives the same result as the above method