# Is it possible to count the function (variable) arguments in a __cdecl with Inline ASM?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, variadic-functions, calling-convention

Is it possible for the callee to iterate (and count) through the function call parameters by offsetting the stack base pointer (rbp) using the inline ASM (x86) without knowing the type or quantity of the arguments?

`void foo(char *arg, ...);`

I am using Intel compiler but its documentation states that it supports GCC style inline assembly. So GCC based example would be sufficient.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int    main(int argc, char **argv){

    uint64_t n;

    __asm__ __volatile__(
      "movq %%rbp, %0\n\t"
      : "=r"(n)
    );

    printf("rbp = 0x%" PRIx64 "\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

[the code in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540825/how-to-access-stack-base-pointer-rbp-using-inline-assembly)

Comment: No, there's no possible way for the callee to figure out how many parameters there are.

Comment: You can use ... passed into a function and have any number of arguments, if that leads to any help

Comment: In nearly all C implementations, no. The original design of C depends on a contract between caller and callee that's up to the programmer to decide and enforce. For example printf's contract is that the number of `%` format specifiers will match the number of arguments.

Comment: Sometimes it isn't even possible to recover arguments unless you know their **types**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible way for this to work is with a unique sentinel value (e.g. a `NULL` pointer) that marks the last argument.

This normally only works when all the args are pointers, e.g. as used by the [POSIX `execl(3)` functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) with signatures like

```
int execl(const char *pathname, const char *arg, ...
                   /* (char  *) NULL */);
```

(Then you don't need inline asm; you can just use C VA_ARG macros.)

---

Also, `rbp` is useless; you don't know whether or not the function was compiled with optimization enabled so it might not be a frame pointer at all.  If you want the frame address in GNU C, use `__builtin_frame_address(0)`.  (Look at the compiler-generated asm to see what it does.  IIRC, it forces `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` for that function and just gives you the value of `rbp`)

And even getting a stack-frame address doesn't help you get register args (first 6 integer/pointer and first 8 FP args in x86-64 System V.  Or first 4 total args in Windows x64.)

Declare your function as variadic and Use `VA_ARG` to read all the variadic args as `uint64_t` so you can check them for zero, or whatever bit-pattern you selected as your sentinel.

**Obviously this requires the cooperation of the caller to pass a sentinel.**

---

BTW, no calling convention called `__cdecl` exists for x86-64.  Microsoft calls theirs x64 `__fastcall` or `__vectorcall`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. It's impossible in the general case.

In the specific case of compiling with debugging symbols on you have a shot at writing code to interpret your own symbols, but this compilation mode is frowned upon for release builds so writing this code is not recommended. It's also completely nonportable but you don't care about that constraint.

Comment: Yup, C doesn't have reflection so getting that from debug info would be a total hack.